# Get the selected posts IDs to use in bulk edit AJAX call

Tags: admin, wp-list-table, bulk, quick-edit

The WordPress codex for [`bulk_edit_custom_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/bulk_edit_custom_box), along with this [bulk edit example](https://github.com/bamadesigner/manage-wordpress-posts-using-bulk-edit-and-quick-edit) use the following piece of JavaScript to create an array of selected post IDs to send with the AJAX call that updates the posts.

```
$bulk_row.find( '#bulk-titles' ).children().each( function() {
    $post_ids.push( $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( /^(ttle)/i, '' ) );
});
```

The full code surrounding this snippet is below.

My list tables have input fields for meta values, and the inline quick edit works successfully, but bulk edit fails. When debugging I found the $post_ids array is empty because there are no elements on my page with the ID `#bulk-titles`.

So my question, where do the `#bulk-titles` elements come from and why would my page not have them?

```
$( '#bulk_edit' ).live( 'click', function() {

    // define the bulk edit row
    var $bulk_row = $( '#bulk-edit' );

    // get the selected post ids that are being edited
    var $post_ids = new Array();

    $bulk_row.find( '#bulk-titles' ).children().each( function() {
        $post_ids.push( $( this ).attr( 'id' ).replace( /^(ttle)/i, '' ) );
    });

    // get the custom fields
    var $item_thickness = $bulk_row.find( 'input[name="item_thickness"]' ).val();
    var $item_width = $bulk_row.find( 'input[name="item_width"]' ).val();
    var $item_length = $bulk_row.find( 'input[name="item_length"]' ).val();

    // save the data
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl, // this is a variable that WordPress has already defined for us
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: 'manage_wp_posts_using_bulk_quick_save_bulk_edit', // this is the name of our WP AJAX function that we'll set up next
            post_ids: $post_ids, // and these are the 2 parameters we're passing to our function
            item_thickness: $item_thickness,
            item_width: $item_width,
            item_length: $item_length
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching through WordPress core I found the following on lines 1051 – 1057 of `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php`

```
if ( post_type_supports( $screen->post_type, 'title' ) ) :
    if ( $bulk ) : ?>
        <div id="bulk-title-div">
            <div id="bulk-titles"></div>
        </div>

<?php else : // $bulk ?>
```

So, in order for the `#bulk-titles` element to be part of your admin list the post type your working with needs to support `title`.

New custom posts types do support `title` by default. My custom post types are not using titles so I had set `supports => false` as an argument passed to [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) call.

Not supplying the `supports` argument or setting it to an array that includes `title` as a member solved the bulk edit problem, and I hid the title on post edit page using CSS.